# Can I have different margins for a list in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to make a list with the following kind of layout:

```
Item one - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
           elit. Proin faucibus arcu diam. Praesent sit amet 
           pharetra nulla. 
Longer item here - Fusce eleifend feugiat lacus. Proin ut dolor 
                   et urna congue fringilla ut non est. Quisque 
                   fermentum fringilla orci a viverra. Nunc 
                   faucibus metus non mi tempus lobortis. 
Shorter - Mauris bibendum volutpat sem, in hendrerit risus quam
          sodales eu. Pellentesque enim quam, adipiscing quis 
          scelerisque nec, volutpat in ligula. Morbi quis ante 
          quam.
```

Is it possible to do this cleanly in Word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. With the line selected, move the bottom arrow in the ruler over to where you want it indented.

[image]

Comment: Although technically, it's not a list anymore. Visually the same effect though.